# OSMDroid get the radius of the map

Tags: kotlin, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm using [OSMDroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) (Open Street Map for Android), and I'm trying to get the radius of the visible map, to send it to my API and get a result scaled correctly.

Here is what I'm doing on iOS using MapKit to achieve this:

```swift
extension MKMapView {

    func topLeftCoordinate() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return self.convert(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), toCoordinateFrom: self)
    }

    func currentRadius() -> Double {
        let topLeftCoordinate = self.topLeftCoordinate()
        return sqrt(pow(centerCoordinate.latitude - topLeftCoordinate.latitude, 2) + pow(centerCoordinate.longitude - topLeftCoordinate.longitude, 2))
    }

}
```

OSMDroid is having a `zoomLevel` but I'm unable to find a way to convert it to what I need, keeping the correct scaling for API.

Thanks in advance for any help or lead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a working solution. It's some kind of magic, but it seems to work correctly (constants were adapted a lot of times before getting the result)

```kotlin
fun MapView.currentRadius(): Double {
    // This is magic
    return 400 / 2.toDouble().pow(zoomLevelDouble)
}
```